# angular $http custom methods

Tags: angularjs, http

I am trying to create an angular app, which uses $http.

What I would like to do, is to create some http requests, but not with the “regular” methods (GET , POST etc.),  but with “non-regular” methods ( check-in, check out as detailed in rfc-5323).

Can anyone please guide me through of how to create those kinds of http requests?
What if would like to do, is something like:

```
$http.checkin(uri,config){
// the data which I would like to check in
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are CHECKIN and CHECKOUT different http methods?  If so, you can specify the these using the "method" property in the http service:

```
var promise = $http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'CHECKIN'
});
```